# Replace Timestamp with PHP variables in Flot Graph

Tags: php, mysql, flot, timestamp

Hi I have a template which uses a flot graph, which uses timestamps to plot the data on the graph as displayed below.

```
var d2 = [
 [1364511661, 2],[1364630461, 20],[1364731261, 28],[1364824861, 37],[1364925661, 76],[1367190061, 88]
     ];
```

what i am trying to do is replace the timestamps with timestamps taken from the MYSQL database, however I can not seem to get it to work. below is my code.

```
var d2 = [ 
            <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            ?>

            <?php { ?> [<?php echo $row['timestamp']; ?>,25 ], <?php } ?>

            ];
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Flot requires that you provide timestamps in milliseconds, that means you have to multiply your PHP timestamps by 1000. [(Source)](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt)

If you are using the `datetime` format for your database timestamp column, that will result in something like "2013-04-28 16:15" and NOT a unix timestamp. You will have to convert it using `strtotime` first, then multiply by 1000 again. You have to use flot's API functions afterwards to make them human readable again.